Transforming symbolic expression to a function
I have the following symbolic expression:
ZZ = \[Delta] + 4*\[Pi]*Z - log[\[Delta]]

I'm trying to define a new function fZZ[\[Delta]_, Z_] that will use this expression and plot it.
I'm trying:
fZZ[\[Delta]_, Z_] := ZZ

But when I do fZZ[0.5, 0.5] I don't get a numerical value, just the symbolic expression of ZZ as the output.
What am I missing?

Use fZZ[\[Delta]_, Z_] := Evaluate@ZZ. Also, use Log vice log

This is easily done if you can use "Set":
ClearAll[fZZ]
ZZ = \[Delta] + 4*\[Pi]*Z - log[\[Delta]];
fZZ[\[Delta]_, Z_] = ZZ;
Information[fZZ]


If you want to use "SetDelayed" you need an additional "Evaluate":
ClearAll[fZZ]
ZZ = \[Delta] + 4*\[Pi]*Z - log[\[Delta]];
fZZ[\[Delta]_, Z_] := Evaluate[ZZ];
Information[fZZ]



Thank you! I thought there was a straightforward way to write a function using an existing expression from previous calculations. Can you please explain why "Set" is needed here?

@ValientProcess as the name says, SetDelayed / := delays the setting until the moment you call the function. That's not what you need here: you need to Set / = immediately. I'd recommend you have a look at the differences between = and :=: distinguishing these two will help you understand Mathematica much better.

@Daniel I think that f[...] := Evaluate[...] is an esoteric abomination that should not be taught to beginners. Better to use = straight away and reduce the confusion.
